# BlackBerry webservice JSON parsing

Tags: java, json, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I have a webservice url that retrieve a JSON as response.I need to send a request to this url and parse JSON from my blackberry App.I have tried some examples but not working.

Anybody have a working example of this?

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
VKS

Comment: please give me the examples which you tested...

Comment: .... and tell us why they are not working so we can HELP YOU FIX IT. But please before use the search box, there are many (I mean MANY) examples in SO

Comment: It depends what is his OS target. JSON API is included to BB 6.0+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this [JSON utilities library for J2ME](https://github.com/upictec/org.json.me/) for parsing JSON on BlackBerry devices.

As for retrieving data over HTTP there's plenty of examples on SO and on the BlackBerry Developer website (e.g. http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/javax/microedition/io/HttpConnection.html) which can help you.